# Выдаёт ошибку в коде, а именно пишет: неизвестное имя 'p' в 16 строке. Программа вычисляет плотность населения

Tags: pascal

```
program naselenie;
var
р: array [1..10] of real;
n: array [1..10] of string;
i, j, imin: integer;
х: real;
r: string;
const
k: array [1..10] of real = (58100, 81200, 10300, 5190, 39100, 57200, 38500, 9800, 5060, 57800);
s: array [1..10] of real = (244.1, 357, 132, 43.1, 504.8, 301.2, 312.7, 92.0, 337, 551);
begin
n[1]:='Великобритания'; n[2]:='Германия'; n[3]:='Греция'; n[4]:='Дания'; n[5]:='Испания'; n[6]:='Италия'; n[7]:='Польша'; n[8]:='Португалия'; n[9]:='Финляндия'; n[10]:='Франция';
for i:=1 to 9 do begin
imin:=i;
for j:=i+1 to 10 do
if x[j]
then x:=p[i];
p[i]:=p[imin];
p[imin]:=x;
r:=n[i];
n[i]:=n[imin];
n[imin]:=r;
end;
writeln ('Отсортированная информация');
for i:=1 to 10 do
writeln (n[i], ' - ', p[i]);
end.
```

Comment: А не влепили ли Вы там по ошибке русскую "эр"?

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь

```
р: array [1..10] of real;
```

русская буква "р".

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь другая ошибка. Пишет в той же строке (16, где была первоначальная ошибка), что нельзя преобразовать real к boolean

Comment: Да, нельзя. Исправляйте.

Comment: Так в этом то и суть... Я не знаю как.

Comment: узнать что такое real, узнать что такое boolean, а потом исправить код так, чтобы он не пытался использовать одно вместо другого.